# Assigning positional parameters to multiple variables in one line

Tags: bash, function, parameter-passing

I was wondering if it is possible to assign positional parameters in a bash function to multiple variables in a single line.

The following works but requires multiple assignment lines:

```
foo () {
   var1=${1}
   var2=${2}
   var3=${3}
   echo "var1=$var1   var2=$var2   var3=$var3"
}

foo 11 "22 22" 33 # Correct result: var1=11   var2=22 22   var3=33
```

The following assigns the input parameters in a single line, but it doesn't handle the second parameter properly:

```
bar () {
    read var1 var2 var3 <<<"$@"
    echo "var1=$var1   var2=$var2   var3=$var3"
}

bar 11 "22 22" 33 # Incorrect result: var1=11   var2=22   var3=22 33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the space character :

```
bar 11 "22\ 22" 33
```

gives :

```
var1=11   var2=22 22   var3=33
```

Comment: @scolfax: With Bertrand Martel‘s hint I suggest: `read var1 var2 var3 <<< "${@// /\ }"`

Comment: Both answers work perfectly. I would be inclined towards Cyrus's solution in order to avoid having to modify the argument values in the function call. Thank you very much for the helpful solutions.

Comment: Will break because: 1. that's an abuse of using `read` without `-r` (so you will have surprises with backslashes); 2. will stop at the first embedded newline; 3. will not preserve leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Not to mention that if you give more than 3 arguments, they all will be concatenated in the last one.

Answer (score 2):

```
g() {
  for k in m p q
  do
    local "$k"="$1"
    shift
  done
  echo m="$m" p="$p" q="$q"
}
g 11 '22 22' 33
```

Note that [local is not specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) by POSIX, but it is
[specified by Bash and Dash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Builtins).

Comment: Btw, your `k` too should be `local`.

Comment: Since you're so attached to dash, you should also warn (as I did) that `shift` will complain if not given enough arguments.

Answer (score -1):

The methods that will try to deserialize `$@` are broken. Don't use them if you want robust code.

Just use a loop:

```
for v in var1 var2 var3; do
    eval $v='$1'
    shift
done
```

Note that the use of `eval` is 100% safe, thanks to the single quotes. To use in a function, in Bash, you can use `local` or `declare -g` instead:

```
foo() {
    local v
    for v in var1 var2 var3; do
        local "$v=$1"
        shift
    done
    printf '%s\n' "var1=$var1" "var2=$var2" "var3=$var3"
}
```

Note that `shift` might complain if you didn't provide enough arguments.

There are many other possible variations on this theme, adapt to your needs.

---

This is greatly superior to some other answers:

- has no problems with embedded newlines, backslashes, funny characters, etc.
- no subshells, temporary files, etc.

---

Final note: if you feel the urge to downvote because I suggested `eval`, make sure you *know better than me* what `eval` does, and why it's dangerous; make sure that you understand why it's 100% safe in this context; and finally, leave a comment to explain why you know better than me why this is wrong.

Comment: The motivation for this thread was to see if there was a satisfactory single-line solution.  If I wanted a multiline solution, what is the downside to the first approach in my initial submission: var1=${1}; var2=${2}; var3=${3}; ...?

Comment: @scolfax: there are no downsides to you approach: by all means, use it! please don't use any other method!